# Filter 3 columns in one dataframe by 3 columns in another, R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

```
df<-structure(list(Name = c("JoeBob", "JoeBob", "JoeBob", "JoeBob", 
"JoeBob", "AliC", "AliC", "AliC", "AliC"), UserNumber = c(1, 
1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 53, 53, 53), Protocol = c("LS-P-Tylenol", "LS-P-Tylenol", 
"LS-P-Tylenol", "AdvilScience", "AdvilScience", "LS-P-Tylenol", 
"CancerDrug", "CancerDrug", "CancerDrug"), Status = c("On Study", 
"Consented", "Eligible", "Consented", "Eligible", "Off Study", 
"On Study", "Eligible", "Consented")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

and

```
    df2<-structure(list(UserNumber = c(1, 4, 2, 53), Protocol = c("LS-P-Tylenol", 
"AdvilScience", "LS-P-Tylenol", "CancerDrug"), Status = c("On Study", 
"Consented", "Off Study", "On Study")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Both dataframes have information on subjects in clinical trials.  Their number in that study, the study name, and their subject status (and a bunch of other columns I didnt list).  The trick is df2 only has one row with their most recent status.

I'd like to filter df so that only the most recent status for each subject in each trial is left.  I.e. instead of 3 rows for JoeBob (who is userNumber 1) in LS-P-Tylenol, we're only left with one row, the row that has "On Study" because thats what status he has in DF2.

It needs to involve all three columns because some users are on multiple trials and some usernumbers are used repeatedly.  Any ideas?

Comment: You may need join or merge i.e. `inner_join(df, df2)`

Comment: Lol duh.  df<-df%>%right_join(df2,by=c("UserNumber","Protocol","Status")) worked wonders.  Lol if you want to answer it i'll mark it as the solution once it lets me

Comment: It's okay.  It will be dupe